# Pear upgrade not working in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, upgrade, pear

When I try to upgrade Pear it shows a message on terminal as follows

> Will upgrade channel://pear.php.net/xml_util
>   Will upgrade channel://pear.php.net/pear
>   Will upgrade channel://pear.php.net/structures_graph
>   WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pear channel-update pear.php.net" to update
>   WARNING: "pear/Console_Getopt" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Console_GetoptPlus"
>   pear/PEAR dependency package "pear/Structures_Graph" downloaded version 1.1.0 is not the recommended version 1.0.4, but may be compatible, use --force to install
>   pear/PEAR dependency package "pear/XML_Util" downloaded version 1.3.0 is not the recommended version 1.2.3, but may be compatible, use --force to install
>   pear/pear dependency package "pear/XML_Util" downloaded version 1.3.0 is not the recommended version 1.2.1, but may be compatible, use --force to install
>   pear/XML_Util cannot be installed, conflicts with installed packages
>   pear/pear dependency package "pear/Structures_Graph" downloaded version 1.1.0 is not the recommended version 1.0.4, but may be compatible, use --force to install
>   pear/Structures_Graph cannot be installed, conflicts with installed packages
>   No valid packages found
>   upgrade-all failed

Answer (score 0):

This issue might come back sometimes and when it does, I simply fix it with the following command:

```
pear upgrade --force
```

Also, `upgrade-all` is deprecated in favor of `upgrade` :)

Comment: it gives same error

Comment: Did you also run: `pear channel-update pear.php.net`